# Change backcolor or background image of a MDI Container form in .net

Tags: c#, .net, mdiparent

i need to change the backcolor or background image of a mdi parent in my application. i tried changing the backcolor or specifying a background image, it won't work. i also tried looping the controls in the form to get the mdiclient and change its backcolor, also zero same result.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319465

Comment: Are you setting up your MDI parent and children before or after the form's Load event occurs. When you debug, can you verify that a control of type MdiClient exists at all. More details about the behavior would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing a simple colour then try the below code, if you are trying to set an image then you can use BackgroundImage with BackgroundImageLayout

```
 MdiClient ctlMDI;
            foreach (Control ctl in this.Controls)
            {
                try
                {
                    ctlMDI = (MdiClient)ctl;

                    // Set the BackColor of the MdiClient control.
                    ctlMDI.BackColor = Color.DarkRed;
                }
                catch (InvalidCastException exc)
                {
                    // Catch and ignore the error if casting failed.
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Private ClientControl As MdiClient

    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()

        ClientControl = Nothing
        For Each Ctl As Control In Me.Controls
            ClientControl = TryCast(Ctl, MdiClient)
            If ClientControl IsNot Nothing Then Exit For
        Next
    End Sub

'iN FORM LOAD

ClientControl.BackColor = Color.Cyan
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it works.

```
foreach (Control control in this.Controls)
{

    // #2
    MdiClient client = control as MdiClient;
    if (!(client == null))
    {
        // #3
        client.BackColor = GetYourColour();
        // 4#
        break;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
  Public Sub MDIBGColor()
        Dim ctl As Control
        Dim ctlMDI As MdiClient

        ' Loop through all of the form's controls looking
        ' for the control of type MdiClient.
        For Each ctl In Me.Controls
            Try

                ' Attempt to cast the control to type MdiClient.
                ctlMDI = CType(ctl, MdiClient)

                ' Set the BackColor of the MdiClient control.
                ctlMDI.BackColor = Me.BackColor

            Catch exc As InvalidCastException
                ' Catch and ignore the error if casting failed.
            End Try
        Next

    End Sub
```

and call the sub on the form load event